# Vote still locked after post was edited in grace period

Tags: feature-request, grace-period, locked-votes

Well, the title says everything: Votes are locked in even though they happend before the post was edited in the grace period.

This happened to me on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27189979/1048572):

1. At 13:42, the answer was posted
2. At 13:52, the answer was edited to amend it with responses to specific questions
3. At 13:56, I downvoted the answer because the first sentence was wrong, and
4. At 13:57, I commented on the post to state this
5. At 13:58, the answerer immediately fixed the first sentence, the edit falling in the grace period of the previous one, and
6. At 13:59, wrote a comment stating that he edited the answer and thanked me for the attention.

Coming back much later (because of the comment, and to look whether the post was corrected), I wanted to remove my downvoted, but the system told me that it was locked in and the post needed to be edited before I could cancel it - which it actually had been.

Please lock votes more liberally to consider such cases (I'm not sure how exactly this happens, so I'm not being more specific).

Comment: Agreed! I have had many such cases myself, and I hate to edit the post (with meaningless newlines or such), just to retract my downvote.

Comment: This was actually regarded as [status-by-design] : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly So if you want it changed, better make it a feature request I guess, if that hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I've never seen any point in downvoting a post for a minor technicality that can be corrected in a few minutes.  Less hassle, much less drama, and not having to deal with this quirk that way.

Comment: You have the rep to just make a minor edit and unlock the vote. Much easier than dealing with grace periods.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Enough rep he certainly has. Would still be a bad work-around, which also does not work for <2k users.